# Find and replace text in all files using PHP

Tags: php, file, replace, directory, find

Hi Everyone,

I have list of PHP files in my project.If I want to replace `index.php` text to `home.php` and save it. It will change in all my PHP file in the directory How can I code this.

I can find and replace in single file but I don't know the way to search in whole directory and replace Kindly help me to know the way. Im new to this section.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do this using any editor "Search in Projects"

Comment: Are you using any kind of IDE? It may have a Replace function that operates on multiple files.

Comment: I know that.I want to do that via PHP code without using IDE tools.

Comment: I mean via code.If I type the text in textbox and replace it will change in PHP file

Comment: There's nothing built into PHP to do this. You'll have to write a script that uses `glob()` or `scandir()`, and recurses into all subdirectories. Then it has to use `file_get_contents()` on each file, `str_replace()` to do the replacement, and `file_put_contents()` to update the file. It will be much easier if you use a tool that's already built for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all files in a directory, `glob(__DIR__.'/*.php')` will give you all php files in current directory. But if you need to do this in a production server only use it if you can run it as a command line function since the web server not should have write access to the files

Answer (score 0):

The [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function might be the function you are looking for.

> Returns an array of files and directories from the directory. (php.net)

Answer (score 0):

If you run PHP on Linux.
The quickest way to replace file content is using sed command.

find **PATH** -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/index.php/home.php/g' {} \;

PHP code:

```
exec("find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/index.php/home.php/g' {} \;");
```